# creating dictionaries from values in pandas columns with repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Considering this sample dataframe:

```
   location emp
0   fac_1   emp1
1   fac_2   emp2
2   fac_2   emp3
3   fac_3   emp4
4   fac_4   emp5
```

It can be recreated by this code:

```
 sample_dict = {'location':['fac_1', 'fac_2', 'fac_2', 'fac_3', 'fac_4'], 'emp':['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3', 'emp4', 'emp5']}
data = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
```

I am trying to create a dictionary with values of every unique "fac" and all associated emp values.  Some of the rows there is only one fac and one emp, so no big deal there.  In many rows, as in the example, there are two different emp values for one fac value.  (See fac_2 in the sample dataframe).

The desired output is a single dictionary like this:

```
{fac_1:emp1, fac_2:[emp2, emp3], fac_3:emp4, fac_4:emp5}
```

I was able to achieve this but via a convoluted route that I am certain, someone here has a more efficient, less error prone way to achieve.  In short, I grouped my df by fac and then used iloc to grab the fac name and the .to_list() function to get all the emp values in a list and then combined that into a dictionary.

Something like this:

```
location = data.iloc[0,1]
emp_lst= data['emp'].to_list()
fac_dict = {facility:np_lst}
```

Someone with some skill at making dictionaries from pandas dataframes I am sure has a more efficient way to achieve the desired output.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.groupby('location')['emp'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'fac_1': ['emp1'], 'fac_2': ['emp2', 'emp3'], 'fac_3': ['emp4'], 'fac_4': ['emp5']}
```

Comment: Okay, so this is genius!  Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Ynjxsjmh's answer was probably better, since it gives you the *exact* output you requested, but I'm glad we could help.

Comment: Yes, based upon my question, you are right.  I realized after seeing your responses that I really need each value to be a list, even if it is only one value, so I can loop through the dictionary in later code.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
out = data.groupby('location')['emp'].agg(lambda col: list(col) if len(col) >= 2 else col).to_dict()
```

```
print(out)

{'fac_1': 'emp1', 'fac_2': ['emp2', 'emp3'], 'fac_3': 'emp4', 'fac_4': 'emp5'}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.  The SO community has been such a great support to my coding journey as people like you and bert2me were on this question.